Timemanager is not reset when finished or onDestroy?
TIMEMANAGE :
package com.example.datvexemphim.Activities;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;

public class TimerManager {
    private static final String PREFS_NAME = "TimerPrefs";
    private static final String KEY_TIME_LEFT = "timeLeft";
    private static CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
    private static long timeLeftInMillis;

    public interface TimerCallback {
        void onTick(long millisUntilFinished);
        void onFinish();
    }

    public static void startTimer(final Context context, final TimerCallback callback) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        timeLeftInMillis = prefs.getLong(KEY_TIME_LEFT, 10 * 60 * 1000); // Default to 10 minutes

        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(timeLeftInMillis, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                callback.onTick(millisUntilFinished);
                saveTimeLeft(context, millisUntilFinished);
                timeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished;
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                callback.onFinish();
                clearTimeLeft(context);
            }
        }.start();
    }

    public static void stopTimer() {
        if (countDownTimer != null) {
            countDownTimer.cancel();
            countDownTimer = null;
        }
    }

    public static void saveTimeLeft(Context context, long timeLeftInMillis) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putLong(KEY_TIME_LEFT, timeLeftInMillis);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public static void clearTimeLeft(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.remove(KEY_TIME_LEFT);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public static void loadTimeLeft(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        timeLeftInMillis = prefs.getLong(KEY_TIME_LEFT, 10 * 60 * 1000); // Default to 10 minutes
        saveTimeLeft(context, timeLeftInMillis);
    }

    public static void setTimeLeft(Context context, long timeInMillis) {
        timeLeftInMillis = timeInMillis;
        saveTimeLeft(context, timeInMillis);
    }
    public static void resetTimer(Context context) {
        saveTimeLeft(context, 10 * 60 * 1000); // Reset to 10 minutes
    }
}

INSIDE ACTIVITY :
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Thông báo");
        builder.setMessage("Bạn có 10 phút để đặt vé và thanh toán, nếu trong khoảng thời gian đó bạn không thanh toán, ghế bạn chọn sẽ bị hủy.");
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(insideActivity.this, SeatActivity.class);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                String[] time = timesccurrent.split("-");
                String timestart = time[0].trim();
                bundle.putInt("movieid", movieid);
                bundle.putInt("roomcurrent", roomcurrent);
                bundle.putString("datecurrent", datecurrent);
                bundle.putString("citycurrent", citycurrent);
                bundle.putString("theatercurrent", theatercurrent);
                bundle.putString("timesccurrent", timesccurrent);
                bundle.putString("timestart", timestart);
                intent.putExtra("bundle2", bundle);
                startActivity(intent);
                // lay ngaygio hien tai , sinh mattmonan, mattve
                LocalDateTime currentDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
                DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
                String formattedDateTime = currentDateTime.format(formatter);
                MATTMONAN ="F"+String.valueOf(userid)+formattedDateTime;
                MATTVE ="T"+String.valueOf(userid)+formattedDateTime;
                dBhelper.insertHoadon(userid,MATTMONAN,MATTVE);
                //TimerManager.setTimeLeft(insideActivity.this, 10 * 60 * 1000);
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Hủy", null);
        builder.show();
    }

SEAT ACTIVITY :
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_seat);
        Log.d(TAG,"onCreate");
        // anh xa
        dBhelper = new DBhelper(this);
        txt_datemovie = findViewById(R.id.txt_datemovieseat);
        txt_timemovie = findViewById(R.id.txt_timemovieseat);
        txt_namemovieseat = findViewById(R.id.txt_namemovieseat);
        txt_chair = findViewById(R.id.txt_chair);
        txt_money = findViewById(R.id.txt_money);
        txt_theaterroomseat = findViewById(R.id.txt_theaterroomseat);
        // dong ho
        countdownTimer = findViewById(R.id.countdownTimer);
        //startTimer( 10 * 60 * 1000); // 10 minutes in milliseconds
        // mo intent lay du lieu
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        bundle =  intent.getBundleExtra("bundle2");
        // set du lieu cho cac truong
        txt_datemovie.setText(bundle.getString("datecurrent"));
        txt_timemovie.setText(bundle.getString("timesccurrent"));
        txt_namemovieseat.setText(dBhelper.getMovieName(bundle.getInt("movieid")));
        txt_theaterroomseat.setText(bundle.getString("theatercurrent")+ " Room "+ String.valueOf(bundle.getInt("roomcurrent")));
        //
        timesccurrent = bundle.getString("timesccurrent");
        movieid = bundle.getInt("movieid");
        roomcurrent = bundle.getInt("roomcurrent");
        theatercurrent = bundle.getString("theatercurrent");
        datecurrent = bundle.getString("datecurrent");
        timestart = bundle.getString("timestart");
        showid = dBhelper.getShowid(movieid,roomcurrent,theatercurrent,datecurrent,timestart);
        // seat
        mylist = new ArrayList<>();

        List<String> listghe= dBhelper.getGhe(showid,roomcurrent);
        List<Integer> listprice = dBhelper.getPrice(showid,roomcurrent);
        for (int i = 0; i < listghe.size(); i++) {
            mylist.add(new Seat(listghe.get(i), listprice.get(i)));
        }
        seatAdapter = new SeatAdapter((Activity) this,R.layout.seat, mylist,showid,roomcurrent,MATTVE);
        gv = findViewById(R.id.gv);
        gv.setAdapter(seatAdapter);
        // btn_next
        btn_finishPaymentButton1 = findViewById(R.id.btn_finishPaymentButton1);
        btn_finishPaymentButton1.setEnabled(false); // Disable button initially
        btn_finishPaymentButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SeatActivity.this, FoodActivity.class );
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("movieid", movieid);
                bundle.putInt("roomcurrent", roomcurrent);
                bundle.putString("datecurrent", datecurrent);
                bundle.putString("theatercurrent", theatercurrent);
                bundle.putString("timesccurrent", timesccurrent);
                bundle.putString("timestart", timestart);
                intent.putExtra("bundle3", bundle);
                intent.putExtra("remainingTime",timeLeftInMillis);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
        //btn_back
        btn_back = findViewById(R.id.btn_back);
        btn_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dBhelper.deleteHoadon(MATTMONAN,MATTVE);
                finish();
            }
        });
        //TimerManager.resetTimer(this);
        TimerManager.loadTimeLeft(this);
        startCountdown();

    }
    private void startCountdown() {
        TimerManager.startTimer(this, new TimerManager.TimerCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                String timeLeftFormatted = String.format("%02d:%02d",
                        millisUntilFinished / 1000 / 60,
                        millisUntilFinished / 1000 % 60);
                countdownTimer.setText(timeLeftFormatted);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                cancelBooking();
            }
        });
    }
    private void cancelBooking() {
        // Hủy MATTVE và MATTMONAN, đặt tất cả ghế đã chọn về trống
        dBhelper.deleteRecordsByMATTMONAN(MATTMONAN);
        dBhelper.deleteRecordsByMATTVE(MATTVE);
        dBhelper.deleteHoadon1(MATTMONAN);
        dBhelper.UpdateGHECHUADAT(dBhelper.getTicketidfromMATTVE(MATTVE));
        TimerManager.stopTimer();
        // Xóa trạng thái thời gian còn lại
        TimerManager.clearTimeLeft(this);
        //TimerManager.resetTimer(this); // Reset timer to 10 minutes
        // Điều hướng trở lại MainActivity
        Intent intent = new Intent(SeatActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(TAG,"onDestroy");
        dBhelper.deleteRecordsByMATTMONAN(MATTMONAN);
        dBhelper.deleteRecordsByMATTVE(MATTVE);
        dBhelper.deleteHoadon1(MATTMONAN);
        dBhelper.UpdateGHECHUADAT(dBhelper.getTicketidfromMATTVE(MATTVE));
        TimerManager.stopTimer();
        TimerManager.clearTimeLeft(this);
        // Xóa trạng thái thời gian còn lại
        //TimerManager.resetTimer(this); // Reset timer to 10 minutes

    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        dBhelper.deleteRecordsByMATTMONAN(MATTMONAN);
        dBhelper.deleteRecordsByMATTVE(MATTVE);
        dBhelper.deleteHoadon1(MATTMONAN);
        dBhelper.updateTINHTRANGToTrong(dBhelper.getTicketidfromMATTVE(MATTVE));
        //dBhelper.UpdateGHECHUADAT(dBhelper.getTicketidfromMATTVE(MATTVE));
        TimerManager.stopTimer();
        // Xóa trạng thái thời gian còn lại
        TimerManager.clearTimeLeft(this);
        //TimerManager.resetTimer(this); // Reset timer to 10 minutes
        finish();
    }


FOOD activity :
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_food);
        Log.d(TAG,"onCreate");
        dBhelper = new DBhelper(this);
        // anh xa id cho cac thanh phan
        txt_datetimefood = findViewById(R.id.txt_datetimefood);
        txt_theaterroom = findViewById(R.id.txt_theaterroom);
        txt_namemoviefood = findViewById(R.id.txt_namemoviefood);
        txt_subtotal = findViewById(R.id.txt_subtotal);
        countdownTimer = findViewById(R.id.countdownTimer);

        //combo
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        bundle =  intent.getBundleExtra("bundle3");
        txt_datetimefood.setText(bundle.getString("datecurrent")+" "+bundle.getString("timesccurrent"));
        txt_theaterroom.setText(bundle.getString("theatercurrent")+"- Room"+bundle.getInt("roomcurrent"));
        txt_namemoviefood.setText(dBhelper.getMovieName(bundle.getInt("movieid")));
        // lay du lieu tu bundle
        timesccurrent = bundle.getString("timesccurrent");
        movieid = bundle.getInt("movieid");
        roomcurrent = bundle.getInt("roomcurrent");
        theatercurrent = bundle.getString("theatercurrent");
        datecurrent = bundle.getString("datecurrent");

        // gio
        //timeLeftInMillis = getIntent().getLongExtra("remainingTime", 10 * 60 * 1000); // Mặc định 10 phút
        //startTimer(timeLeftInMillis);

        mylist = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> listname = dBhelper.getNameFood();
        List<Integer> listprice = dBhelper.getPriceFood();
        List<Bitmap> listimage = dBhelper.getImageFood();
        for (int i = 0; i < listimage.size(); i++) {
            mylist.add(new Combo(listimage.get(i),listname.get(i),listprice.get(i)));
        }
        comboAdapter = new ComboAdapter(this , R.layout.combo, mylist,MATTMONAN);
        comboAdapter.setOnQuantityChangeListener(new ComboAdapter.OnQuantityChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onQuantityChanged() {
                updateSubtotal();
            }
        });
        foodListView = findViewById(R.id.foodListView);
        foodListView.setAdapter(comboAdapter);


        btn_finishPaymentButton2 = findViewById(R.id.btn_finishPaymentButton2);
        btn_finishPaymentButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //countDownTimer.cancel();
                Intent intent = new Intent(FoodActivity.this, Waitforpay.class );
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("movieid", movieid);
                bundle.putInt("roomcurrent", roomcurrent);
                bundle.putString("datecurrent", datecurrent);
                bundle.putString("theatercurrent", theatercurrent);
                bundle.putString("timesccurrent", timesccurrent);
                intent.putExtra("remainingTime",timeLeftInMillis);
                intent.putExtra("bundle4",bundle);
                startActivity(intent);
                //finish();

            }
        });
        //TimerManager.resetTimer(this);
        TimerManager.loadTimeLeft(this);
        startCountdown();
    }
    private void startCountdown() {
        TimerManager.startTimer(this, new TimerManager.TimerCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                String timeLeftFormatted = String.format("%02d:%02d",
                        millisUntilFinished / 1000 / 60,
                        millisUntilFinished / 1000 % 60);
                countdownTimer.setText(timeLeftFormatted);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                cancelBooking();
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(TAG,"onDestroy");
        dBhelper.deleteRecordsByMATTMONAN(MATTMONAN);
        dBhelper.deleteRecordsByMATTVE(MATTVE);
        dBhelper.deleteHoadon1(MATTMONAN);
        dBhelper.UpdateGHECHUADAT(dBhelper.getTicketidfromMATTVE(MATTVE));
        TimerManager.stopTimer();
        // Xóa trạng thái thời gian còn lại
        TimerManager.clearTimeLeft(this);
        //TimerManager.resetTimer(this); // Reset timer to 10 minutes
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        TimerManager.loadTimeLeft(this);
        startCountdown();
    }

    private void updateSubtotal() {
            subtotal = 0;
        for (Combo combo : mylist) {
            subtotal += combo.getComboprice() * combo.getQuantity();
        }
        txt_subtotal.setText(subtotal + "đ");
    }
    private void cancelBooking() {
        // Hủy MATTVE và MATTMONAN, đặt tất cả ghế đã chọn về trống
        dBhelper.deleteRecordsByMATTMONAN(MATTMONAN);
        dBhelper.deleteRecordsByMATTVE(MATTVE);
        dBhelper.deleteHoadon1(MATTMONAN);
        TimerManager.stopTimer();
        TimerManager.clearTimeLeft(this);
        // Xóa trạng thái thời gian còn lại
        //TimerManager.resetTimer(this); // Reset timer to 10 minutes
        // Điều hướng trở lại MainActivity
        Intent intent = new Intent(FoodActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

waitforpay activity:
`@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_waitforpay);
        //anh xa cac thanh phan
        txt_namemovieend = findViewById(R.id.txt_namemovieend);
        txt_theaterroompayment = findViewById(R.id.txt_theaterroompayment);
        txt_datetimepayment = findViewById(R.id.txt_datetimepayment);
        txt_ticket = findViewById(R.id.txt_ticket);
        txt_totalprice = findViewById(R.id.txt_totalprice);
        txt_totalpriceticket = findViewById(R.id.txt_totalpriceticket);
        lv_fooditemwfp = findViewById(R.id.lv_fooditemwfp);
        // xu li cum thanh phan thong tin rap va suat chieu
        dBhelper = new DBhelper(this);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        bundle = intent.getBundleExtra("bundle4");
        txt_namemovieend.setText(dBhelper.getMovieName(bundle.getInt("movieid")));
        txt_theaterroompayment.setText(bundle.getString("theatercurrent") + "- Room" + bundle.getInt("roomcurrent"));
        txt_datetimepayment.setText(bundle.getString("datecurrent") + " " + bundle.getString("timesccurrent"));
        roomcurrent = bundle.getInt("roomcurrent");
        List<String> listgheid = dBhelper.getGheidfromTTve(MATTVE);
        txt_ticket.setText(String.valueOf(slghe) + " x " + "Seat : " + seats);
        //int price = dBhelper.getTongtien(MATTVE);
        int ticketprice = totalPrice;
        txt_totalpriceticket.setText(String.valueOf(ticketprice) + "đ");
        int foodprice = subtotal;
        finaltongtien = subtotal + totalPrice;
        txt_totalprice.setText(String.valueOf(finaltongtien) + "đ");
        // xu li listview
        mylist = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> listfoodid = dBhelper.getFoodidfrom(MATTMONAN);
        List<Integer> listsl = dBhelper.getSLfromTTMONAN(MATTMONAN);
        List<String> listfoodname = dBhelper.getNamefromMONAN(listfoodid);
        List<Integer> listprice = dBhelper.getPricefromMONAN(listfoodid);
        for (int i = 0; i < listfoodname.size(); i++) {
            mylist.add(new Foodpay(listfoodname.get(i), listprice.get(i), listsl.get(i)));
        }
        // set kt thay doi listview boi sl item
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = lv_fooditemwfp.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = (int) (listfoodname.size() * 62 *((lv_fooditemwfp.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density)));
        lv_fooditemwfp.setLayoutParams(params);
        foodAdapter = new FoodAdapter(Waitforpay.this, R.layout.list_item_food_waitforpay, mylist);
        lv_fooditemwfp.setAdapter(foodAdapter);

        countdownTimer = findViewById(R.id.countdownTimer);
        btn_finishPaymentButton3 = findViewById(R.id.btn_finishPaymentButton3);
        btn_finishPaymentButton3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showPaymentDialog();
            }
        });
        TimerManager.loadTimeLeft(this);
        startCountdown();
    }
    private void startCountdown() {
        TimerManager.startTimer(this, new TimerManager.TimerCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                String timeLeftFormatted = String.format("%02d:%02d",
                        millisUntilFinished / 1000 / 60,
                        millisUntilFinished / 1000 % 60);
                countdownTimer.setText(timeLeftFormatted);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                cancelBooking();
            }
        });
    }
    private void showPaymentDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Thông báo");
        builder.setMessage("Bạn đã đặt vé thành công");
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // cap nhat lai trang thai hoa don
                dBhelper.UpdateHoadon(MATTMONAN, finaltongtien);
                // cap nhat trang thai thanh toan mon an va thanh toan ve
                dBhelper.UpdateTTVE(MATTVE);
                dBhelper.UpdateTTMONAN(MATTMONAN);
                dBhelper.UpdateGHE(dBhelper.getTicketidfromMATTVE(MATTVE));
                completePayment();
            }
        });
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.show();
    }

    private void completePayment() {
        TimerManager.stopTimer();
        TimerManager.clearTimeLeft(this);
        //TimerManager.resetTimer(this);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Waitforpay.this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    private void cancelBooking() {
        // Hủy MATTVE và MATTMONAN, đặt tất cả ghế đã chọn về trống
        dBhelper.deleteRecordsByMATTMONAN(MATTMONAN);
        dBhelper.deleteRecordsByMATTVE(MATTVE);
        dBhelper.deleteHoadon1(MATTMONAN);
        dBhelper.UpdateGHECHUADAT(dBhelper.getTicketidfromMATTVE(MATTVE));
        TimerManager.stopTimer();
        TimerManager.clearTimeLeft(this);
        //TimerManager.resetTimer(this);
        // Điều hướng trở lại MainActivity
        Intent intent = new Intent(Waitforpay.this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(TAG,"onDestroy");
        dBhelper.deleteRecordsByMATTMONAN(MATTMONAN);
        dBhelper.deleteRecordsByMATTVE(MATTVE);
        dBhelper.deleteHoadon1(MATTMONAN);
        dBhelper.UpdateGHECHUADAT(dBhelper.getTicketidfromMATTVE(MATTVE));
        TimerManager.stopTimer();
        TimerManager.clearTimeLeft(this);
        // Xóa trạng thái thời gian còn lại
        //TimerManager.resetTimer(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        TimerManager.loadTimeLeft(this);
        startCountdown();

`
MAIN,INSIDE,SEAT,FOOD,WAIT
I have tried many different ways, but when I press finish in the wait activity, the time is not reset. I want to handle the clock when in Seat, Food, Wait running as the same clock when returning or continuing, the clock still runs correctly. When pressing finish, or when returning from Seat to Inside, the clock must be reset. For example, if the user exits the application while booking a ticket, the time will be erased, returning to 10 minutes.

Someone may be able to help you, but that is a lot of code. Instead, consider writing a [mre]. You may even discover the problem yourself, in the process of writing/testing it.
